# User Log in with entities

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web, entities

I'm making a web aplication, using NetBeans, with Glashfish and derby database.

I'm trying to make a logging page using jsp.

Firstly i did it making a conection to the db and throwing sentences, but this is, apart from ugly, so hard working, when the app grows, so i made the enitty class, and the sesion beans. The problem is that i dont know how to integrate the use of the entity in the jsp page.

Here is the code.

```
session.setAttribute("usuario",usuario);
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"); 
Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TFG", "root", "root"); 
Statement stmt = conexion.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NIVEL,ID FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '" + usuario + "' AND PASS = '" + pass + "'");
```

Comment: did you mean how to access data stored in session on JSP ?

Comment: Is the question that you don't know how to call your java class from a jsp page?  you may want post some code here.

Comment: This is my actual code
---
session.setAttribute("usuario",usuario);
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TFG", "root", "root");
        Statement stmt = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NIVEL,ID FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '" + usuario + "' AND PASS = '" + pass + "'");   
And i want to transform it to be able to call a function from my entities wich return me a user type = null in case that the user doesnt exist or a object User instead

Comment: so you want to know how you get the data in rs to be available in your jsp scripting?

Comment: No, srry for the miss understood, but i would like to stop using pools and use entitys and sesions instead

Comment: Victor, I know English is difficult, but it would be helpful if your question was more concise.

Comment: Yes, you are completly righ, will try to make it easier.
My mainly problem is this: I'm making a web aplication, and i can do it easier or harder with a connection pool and throwing sentence to the database, but, instead, i would like to use the entity class from javaEE, the mainly problem is that i dont know how to integrate it in my jsp page, for example, if my jsp index, is for a login, i dont know how to use the enitity to check the user/pass in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up a book on the subject. Your use case is pretty straight forward. Good luck.